# Mean ranks and standard errors of Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: r, anova, kruskal-wallis-test

While it's easy to compute the p-value of Krsukal-Wallis non-parametric test using the `kruskal.test()` function, I don't know how to compute the mean ranks and standard errors for each group.

For instance suppose the following example:

```
x <- data.frame(group=rep(1:2,each=10),height=runif(20))
kruskal.test(x$height, g=x$group)
#   Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
# data:  x$height and x$group
# Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.0057, df = 1,
# p-value = 0.9397
```

It returns only p-value, but not the mean ranks and standard errors for each group.

I have also tried the `verboseBarplot()` of package "WGCNA", it generates a bar plot with standard errors, but I think the height of bars are not mean of the "ranks", but rather seem to be normal mean values.

**Update**

I have done the analysis as follows, that computes mean ranks and standard errors for each column of x, based on "group" column which is first. Is it correct?

```
library(plyr)
se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
colSe <- function(x) apply(x, 2, se)
y <- sapply(2:ncol(x),function(i) rank(x[,i])) 
y <- cbind(x$group,y)
colnames(y)<-colnames(x)
y <- data.frame(y)
m <- ddply(y, .(group),colMeans)
m.se <- ddply(y, .(group), colSe)
m.se$group <- m$group
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to compare just two groups, you'll have to use the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test / Mann-Whitney test (for independent groups) or the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test (for dependent groups). The Kruskall-Wallis test is used when you want to compare more than two (independent) groups.

Creating some sample data with two grouping variables; one with two levels (sex) and one with four levels (group):

```
x <- data.frame(group=rep(1:4,each=10),sex=rep(1:2,each=20),height=runif(40))
```

Loading required packages:

```
require(pastecs)  # for descriptive statistics
require(pgirmess) # for post hoc tests
```

When you want to compare the male participants with the female partipants, you use the Wilcoxon Signed Rank test (which is more or less the same as the Mann-Whitney test):

```
wilcox.test(height ~ sex, data = x, paired = FALSE)
by(x$height, x$sex, stat.desc, basic = FALSE)
```

A Kruskall-Wallis test for group (which has four levels):

```
kruskal.test(height ~ group, data = x)
```

Comparing the ranks for the groups:

```
# creating a rank variable
x$heightRank <- rank(x$height)

# getting the descriptive statistics for the groups
by(x$heightRank, x$group, stat.desc, basic = FALSE)

# post-hoc test for identifying statistical significant differences between the groups
kruskalmc(height ~ group, data = x)
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I understand your answer, but `paired=FALSE` does not make sense to me in the first `wilcox.test()`. Is it required/true?

Comment: You have to use `paired=FALSE` when you compare independent groups. Use `paired=TRUE` when you want to compare dependent groups (e.g. repeated measures).